# Application crashes on click on device back button?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I am working on android phonegap application.I have written some code to make back button disable.

```
function onLoad(){
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}
function onDeviceReady() {
document.addEventListener("backbutton", backKeyDown, true);
console.log("device is ready");
}
function backKeyDown() {
try{
    /document.body.style.cursor = 'none';
    if(!(($('#LoadingImage').is(':visible') )){
        /*document.body.style.cursor = 'none';*/
        jConfirm('Are you sure you want to exit?', 'Confirm', function(r) {        
            if (r == true) {
            localStorage.clear();
                navigator.app.exitApp();
            }      
        });  
    }
    else{

    }

}
catch(err){
    alert(err.message);
}
finally{

}
}
```

where loading Image is a div which is showing loading symbol.

```
 <div id="LoadingImage" style="display:none">
            <div id="floatingCirclesG">
                <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_01">
                </div>
                <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_02">
                </div>
                <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_03">
                </div>
                <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_04">
                </div>
                <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_05">
                </div>
                <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_06">
                </div>
                <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_07">
                </div>
                <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_08">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

My problem is when loading div shows and i click on device back button application crashes in galaxy ace version 2.3 but its working fine in galaxy s2 version 4.0.Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance!